# Object inside a class cannot be seen inside a method's for loop

Tags: c#, object

My sample code:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    object a = new object ();

    static void methodA()
    {
        string[] tests = {"test1","test2","test3"}
        foreach(string test in tests)
        {
            a.SetValue(""); //object a cannot be seen
        }
    }
}
```

Object cannot be seen. How can I use the object inside a `for` loop?

Answer (score 6):

Your method is `static`. You cannot access non-static fields from static methods. Consider if your method (or variable) is supposed to be static and

1. Declare your variable with `static` keyword
2. Remove `static` keyword from the method declaration

Here is the [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The object is not static but the method is.  Change the declaration to:

```
static Object a = new Object ();
```

and it will be accessible from within your loop.

Your other option is to make the method not `static`.  Which you choose really depends on which behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is static, that's why you can't access the object. Try making your object static as well.